# existing excel formulas into power query

Tags: excel-formula, powerbi, powerquery, excel-2016

I have an Excel workbook with a number of sheets, each sheet containing more than 500 columns. Each column has Excel formulas to get the data from a master sheet.

I want to these formulas into power query.

Is there any way I can transfer these formulas into power query?

I am using Excel 2016.

Comment: @MarcelBeug is right. PowerQuery is very effective in terms of data transformation, but to effectively use it in complex solutions you definitely need a data model.

Answer (score 3):

Excel and Power Query are too different to allow for something like a button that would convert Excel formulas to Power Query code.

Probably it is not a good idea to have the data in the Excel sheets moved into Power Query without first making a redesign of the data structure: typically Excel data is organized in flat files (sheets and or tables), while Power Query structures data into a data model.

My approach would be to design the data model and then create the code in Power Query (using the available menu options and/or manually in the formula bar / advanced editor) to get the data into the data model.

Probably I would use an overview of the formulas used in the Excel sheets (either via tab FORMULAS - Show Formulas OR via a separate overview using Excel function FORMULATEXT).